# select dom which have css property cursor:pointer

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

```
<div class="classname">some test<div>
<style> div.classname{cursor:pointer}</style>
```

I want to select dom which have cursor pointer assigned by CSS example above

not sure something like below

```
document.querySelector('[cursor=pointer]')
```

Comment: Are there going to be a lot of classes with the cursor pointer, and if you're going to have classes anyway why not just make a class called like "point-cursor" and just assign that to elements along with your other classes. Then you can much more easily query select anything with that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i came up with below solution

```
function getCursorPointerDomArray()
{
    let ar=[];
    let dom=document;
    function iterateDomNode(dom)
    {
        let c,noIterate=false;
        try{   
            c=getComputedStyle(dom);
            if(c.getPropertyValue('cursor')=='pointer')
            {
                ar.push(dom);         
                noIterate=true;
            }
        }catch(e)
        {

        }
        if(dom.hasChildNodes() && noIterate==false)
        {
            for(let i=0;i<dom.childNodes.length;i++)
            {
                iterateDomNode(dom.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }        
    }   
    iterateDomNode(dom) 
    return ar;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
document.querySelector('[style*="cursor:pointer"]')
```

but this only works for *inline* styles which we set on elements directly using `style` attribute like this:

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('[style*="cursor:pointer"]')
console.log( elem )
```

```html
<div class="classname" style="cursor:pointer">some test<div>
```

---

To find the dom element based on *computed* style <sup>*( like in this case using the class )*</sup> we will need to loop through all elements on the page and then use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method like:

```js
(function() {
  // Get all elements on the page
  let elms = [...document.querySelectorAll('*')];
  
  // loop through all elements and getComputedStyle 
  elms.some(el => {
    let compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    
    // Find the cursor property of current dom element
    if (compStyles.getPropertyValue('cursor') == 'pointer') {
      console.log('Element found')
      console.log(el)
      return true; // break the loop here
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
div.classname {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div class="classname">some test
<div>
```